# How to fix warning "Warning message: In nloptr(x0 = x0, eval_f = f,..... NAs introduced by coercion to integer range"

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I am using the R package nloptr to solve a non-linear optimization problem. I am getting the following warning

```
    Warning message:
    In nloptr(x0 = x0, eval_f = f, lb = lowerb, ub = upperb, eval_g_ineq = g,  :
    NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Where might be the problem?

The problem is not in my input data as I have used the same data on other formulation and there I have got no warnings.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without a sample of your data to reproduce the error.  What I can tell you is that some transformation that `nloptr` tried to do of your data went awry.

Comment: there seem to be some result numbers that are so big, that they
do not fit into an integer value. I don't know how i can fix that